# PXE use part of my kickstart file

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to deploy an easier way to configure my computers.

I'm using an Ubuntu Server as DHCP and tftp server to manage PXE installations.

I find help with [ubuntu netboot](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/netboot) and with [ubuntu PXE install server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallServer)

Everything is fine until my menu on my futur well installed computer.

It tries to connect to ubuntu mirrors.. It's a huge problem because it doesn't have internet connection !

I've mount an image of Ubuntu Trusty on my Ubuntu Server (thank to Apache) and my link is available.

Here is my code

```
DEFAULT vesamenu.c32
timeout 100
display boot.msg
menu background splash.png
menu title Welcome to my awesome installer

label Install new computer
  kernel ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux
  append ks=http://ip.local.server/ks.cfg vga=normal initird=ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz
```

When I make my decision to select "Install new computer" it seems working but finally the installer installs network tools (configure ip v4, searched dhcp, configured ip v6) and fail when try to connect to Ubuntu mirror. But I don't want it to connect to mirrors because files are already downloaded on my Ubuntu Server (http://ip.local.server/ubuntu-trusty).

It didn't seems to understand that my `ks.cfg` is here (`http://ip.local.server/ks.cfg`).

`ks.cfg`:

```
#Generated by Kickstart Configurator
#platform=x86

#Install OS instead of upgrade
install
#Use Web installation
url --url http://192.168.3.1/ubuntu-trusty


#### Mirror settings ###

d-i mirror/country          string fr
d-i mirror/http/hostname    string http://192.168.3.1
d-i mirror/http/directory   string /ubuntu-trusty
d-i mirror/suite            string trusty
#d-i mirror/country          string fr

#System language
lang fr_FR
#Language modules to install
langsupport fr_FR
#System keyboard
keyboard fr
#System mouse
mouse
#System timezone
timezone Europe/Paris
#Root password
rootpw --disabled
#Initial user
user myuser --fullname "MyUser" --iscrypted --password $1$tDwZTgoh$a25ayXUItWDWxdQlUg0Tk1
#Reboot after installation
reboot
#Use text mode install
text
#Use interactive kickstart installation method
interactive

#System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr 
#Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr yes
#Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel 
#Disk partitioning information
part swap --size 4000 
part / --fstype ext4 --size 1 --grow 
#System authorization infomation
auth  --useshadow  --enablemd5 
#Network information
network --bootproto=static --ip=192.168.3.222 --netmask=255.255.255.0 --nameserver=192.168.3.1 --gateway=192.168.3.1
#Firewall configuration
firewall --disabled
#X Window System configuration information
#xconfig --depth=32 --resolution=2048x1536 --defaultdesktop=GNOME --startxonboot
```

This `ks.cfg` file was generated directly from `system-config-kickstart`.

**Edit:**

I've set a static ip on my `ks.cfg` and with a `tcpdump` on my server I can see requests with this ip. This means my `ks.cfg` file is read but I still don't know why it's searching to access mirrors on the web instead of searching on my server.

Does anyone have an idea of this mirror researches that fail my PXE installation?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me ask if you have turned your HTTP server on? in your case the **ks.cfg** file is going to be retrieved by an http transfer from

```
http://ip.local.server/ks.cfg
```

Next for the mirror parameters in your ks file you have to add something like

```
(Ubuntu)
#### Mirror settings.
preseed         mirror/country string manual
preseed         mirror/http/hostname string thinkmate5.ma.utexas.edu
preseed         mirror/http/directory string /mirror/precise/ubuntu
preseed         apt-setup/security_host string thinkmate5.ma.utexas.edu
preseed         apt-setup/security_path string /mirror/precise/ubuntu

(Debian)
#### Mirror settings.

d-i mirror/country          string fr
d-i mirror/http/hostname    string http://ip.local.server
d-i mirror/http/directory   string /ubuntu
d-i mirror/suite            string trusty
#d-i    mirror/http/proxy   string
```

you could also add mirror settings at the "append" line like

```
mirror/country=manual mirror/http/hostname=aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd mirror/http/directory=/directoryXX mirror/http/proxy=""
```

Comment: My HTTP server is turn on. I can access to my `ks.cfg` file through my browser. I've added your lines on my `ks.cfg` file and this the same problem about checking mirrors.

Comment: I've added a part about a static ip that I've added. My `ks.cfg` file is read but it's still searching mirrors on the web.

Comment: please add to your question the exact text in your ks dealing with the repository parameters

Comment: I've added the ks file.

Comment: see my answer with the correct format

Comment: It's better but I still have a problem with mirrors that it searches. It says archive has been corrupted. I have mount Ubuntu 14.04 image on `/var/www/html/ubuntu-trusty`. Is it equal to a mirror link if I access to it through `http://192.168.3.1/ubuntu-trusty'?` On `/var/log/syslog` I can read `DEBUG: resolver (libc6-udeb): package doesn't exist (ignored)` `anna-install: Queueing udeb apt-mirror-setup for later installation`.

Comment: I read you comment 10 times and I do not know what you mean... is now your ks finding your mirror yes or no? the rest sure is a problem with your mirror/http/directory variable.

Comment: What I meant is that on my `http://192.168.3.1/ubuntu-trusty` I have the result of `mount -o loop iso9660 /my/folder/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso /var/www/html/ubuntu-trusty`, is `http://192.68.3.1/ubuntu-trusty` equal to what Ubuntu calls `mirror`? Is a mount command enough or not to create a mirror?

Comment: yes copying/mapping the ISO content is valid as ubuntu repository. but please consider ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso is a "live" distribution then it does not have the typical ubuntu install. See here more info on how to PXE the different versions of Ubuntu with its different append parameters http://vercot.com/~serva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html

Comment: I've downloaded the initrd package to complete my PXE installation. You're right, the problem comes from the my mirror directory but maybe from my `default` file too. I don't even know why it's not working because it has found the ks.cfg file. This means my HTTP directory is available.. Do you have an idea about the `default` file ? Is anything wrong with my syntax? Did I miss something?

Comment: At this moment I do not even know what's your problem, probably you are just loading an initrd that is not meant to be used for PXE... The default file looks ok if you are able to retrieve the kf.cfg.  Do not re-invent the wheel; you first have to define what you want to install and see how Serva does it, then you can do the same thing with your own server. PXE is not simple, it is not that you will just put a couple of files here and there write an ks and everything will work.

Comment: You said the right thing. The problem came from the `live` version of Ubuntu. I forgot Ubuntu and try with Debian according to this website `http://www.unix-experience.fr/2013/installation-automatisee-de-debian-par-le-reseau/` (in french) and netboot proposed on debian's web site + Debian 7.7. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I'm glad you solved it, please accept the answer.

Comment: Final note, it's working with Debian but on the `ks.file` it's with the `i-d` command and not with `pressed`.

Comment: that's right Ubuntu and Debian are not identical and remember KS is a technology borrowed from Red Hat then go figure the differences among all these different versions... I edited the answer adding both versions.

Answer (score 0):

Booting with kickstart have multiple layers and not all information is send from one layer to the next.

Even though your DHCP server have send an ip and information about bootfiles to the loader program ( often that is syslinux or pxelinux ) this information is not send to the OS when it boots. The kickstart file is only read after the system boots and the install program have started ( often that is anaconda ).

I think you need to pass ip=dhcp somewhere on the append line. In my setup I also have keymap=dk lang=en_US on this line to setup language and keyboard settings.